# Center plot when using pyplot errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason I cannot find out how to change the alignment when using `numpy.pyplot.errorbar`. I am creating a plot like this:

```
plt.errorbar(nums, vafmean, yerr=vafstddev, linestyle="None", fmt='o')
```

The output plot displays mostly fine, but the data is pushed out to the far right and left edges of the plot, and there is no way that I can figure out to add something like `align='center'` to the plot. So I am looking for a way to get the data to plot more towards the center of the graph.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the limits of the graph,

```
plt.xlim(-2,3)
```

or you may create some padding around,

```
plt.margins(x=0.4)
```